# How to find number of rows affected by INSERT INTO statement in ColdFusion And MySql Database?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have following query in ColdFusion:

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="test">
    INSERT INTO test (id,name) VALUES (1,"santy"),(2,"raj"),(3,"nil")
</cfquery>
```

I want to find number of affected rows count. Is there any way to find this in ColdFusion?

Comment: Please mention Database server you are using. Solutions may differ based on it. It would be helpful for others visiting this page.

Comment: @Pankaj Yes sure and thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<cftransaction>
    <cfquery name="test" datasource="test">
        INSERT INTO test (id,name) VALUES (1,"santy"),(2,"raj"),(3,"nil")
    </cfquery>
    <cfquery name="test1" datasource="test">
        SELECT ROW_COUNT() AS numberOfRowsAffected
    </cfquery>
</cftransaction>
<cfdump var="#test1.numberOfRowsAffected#">
```

**Or**

You can make changes in the settings to allow multiple sql statements withing one cfquery. To make that happen, make changes as mentioned below:

In ColdFusion Admin, go to your Data Source definition form and add **allowMultiQueries=true** to the Connection String box. Once you do that, you can pass multiple semi-colon separated queries in a single CFQUERY tag. Just make sure you're using CFQUERYPARAM to screen for SQL Injection Attacks.

Comment: @Tushar Nice one! Didn't know about it.

Comment: Seriously, I always thought that variable object in `result` attribute holds all the information about the execution of that query but turns out `MySQL` is behaving differently. Very helpful and creative answer @Tushar

Comment: *make sure you're using CFQUERYPARAM* Even if you are not using `allowMultiQueries`. While arguably sql injection protection is probably the most important benefits, cfqueryparam is really designed to help boost performance for statements executed multiple times with varying values.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one.

```
<cfquery datasource="test" result="myResult">
  INSERT INTO test (id,name) VALUES (1,"santy"),(2,"raj"),(3,"nil")
</cfquery>
<cfset getNumberOfRecords = listLen(#myResult.generated_key#)>
<cfdump var="#getNumberOfRecords#">
```

`myResult.generated_key` contains the list of generated ids, so we can find how many rows have been inserted when we use `listLen()` function.

Comment: That is `MySQL` solution @GunvantW. But does it work for update as well?

Comment: There is a complete solution worth looking into: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7861180/3098962

Comment: @GunvantW. This solution is also working fine with my problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `result` attribute and then access the `recordCount` key of the result.

```
<cfquery result="myResult" datasource="test">
  INSERT INTO test (id,name) VALUES (1,"santy"),(2,"raj"),(3,"nil")
</cfquery> 

<cfdump var="#myResult.recordCount#">
```

Comment: It is always give result as 1. Even if there are n number rows affected by insert statement.

Comment: @JohnWhish, Ideally this should work but on some databases it doesn't.

Comment: @SantoshDahifale It should work. Which database are you using?

Comment: @SantoshDahifale - Result only works for single value inserts. For multiple values, you need to use another method (most likely dbms specific), like SQL Server's OUTPUT clause, etcetera...